# Start a hangout chat from web

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I am trying to make a hangouts button on a user page profile that when clicked will take the user to the hangouts app and start a hangouts chat with the person specified.

Just to make things clear I am trying to make a CHAT start not a Video call or Hangouts on Air.

Current code:

```
            <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

            <div id="placeholder-rr"></div>

            <script>
                $( document ).ready(function() {


                    gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-rr', {
                    'render': 'createhangout',
                    'hangout_type': 'normal',
                    'invites' : [{'id': '109883513693796164843','invite_type': 'PROFILE'}],
                    'widget_size': 175
                    });

                });
            </script>
```

But for some reason no matter what i tinker with it allways starts a Hangouts on Air.

If somebody can help me i would really apreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hangouts API only supports video hangouts. If you would like integration with text chats [search for or create feature requests](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).